# Struts2 Annotation @RequestParameter

Tags: java, url, parameters, struts2, request

I am following [this](http://www.struts2.info/displaycontent/content/better-urls-with-struts2) tutorial to create a SEO friendly url with struts2, however in my class

```
@RequestParameter
public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}
```

this error shows up on `@RequestParameter`

```
RequestParameter cannot be resolved to a type
```

I have included the struts2-core jara in my `web-inf/lib` but I am still wondering how come it is returning an error there.

Comment: do you have an import statement for RequestParameter?

Comment: that's the problem, whenever I try eclipse to auto import it, it doesn't find the necessary class or package for it. although i have imported struts2-core jar

Comment: I don't think that is in the struts core... I can't say for sure where you will find it. I know that Spring uses it but...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Struts2 does not have any `@RequestParameter` in it...

> By the way, you don't need it at all to run your example.
>
> Just remove it, compile and deploy :)

You may want to take a look at the [Struts2 REST plugin](http://struts.apache.org/2.3.7/docs/rest-plugin.html) too.

And searching a bit, it turns out that it is a [custom Annotation created by the author of the blog post](http://www.struts2.info/displaycontent/content/identifying-struts2-setters-with-a-custom-annotation), with the only goal of helping his `IDE`, `IntelliJ`, to avoid highlighting the `Setters` as unused...

@StevenBenitez (that is a SO user too), you better remove your custom `Annotation` from the other examples in your blog, to avoid confusions on users who have not declared it nor read the blog post in which you describe it :)

Comment: Oh I see, I'll try that tutorial again. also what does the REST plugin actually do?

Comment: From the linked doc source: "The REST Plugin simplifies REST-style resources to be consumed by both human and machine clients. **The goals are to 100% follow Ruby on Rails-style REST URL conventions and enable XML-free resource development. **It builds on the Convention Plugin to support automatic configuration of both actions and results."